# how to convert the exp into java exp

Tags: java

I have a homework

[image]

and i dont know how to convert the expression into Java.
Sometimes I have to put parentheses and the solution it will change so, 
I'm not sure, if my code is right or not.

I wrote this code:

```
double number1 = 10;
double number2 = 20;
double number3 = 30;

int sum = (int) (number1 + number2 + number3);
double average = sum / 3;

int product = (int) (number1 * number2 * number3);
double exp = (10.5 / number3) + (5 + number1 * number2) / (number3 - number1) * 12;

System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
System.out.println("The product is: " + product);
System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
System.out.println("The expression result is: " + exp);
```

Comment: Well for one I don't see why you are declaring your numbers as doubles and then assigning them to an INT value. You are losing any decimal precision as it will only keep the INT.

Comment: It looks good to me, what's you're input, output and expected results?

Comment: actually your calculation of exp ist correct

Comment: @ergonaut i think you are right. his numbers are off. only problem i see. the casting stuff should not change the outcome here.

Comment: I think your numbers should be 10, 15, 35 or something else since they don't match your first 3 statements.

Comment: As ergonaut said, your code gives the same results as the sample output for numbers 10, 15, 35. But only if the second fraction in the expression is interpreted as integer division (as you currently have); otherwise the expression result would be `74.7`.

Comment: @Cinnam the second fraction is not integer division, since all `number`-variables are `double`

Comment: @JohnnyAW Ah, you're right. So if it *was* integer division, the result would be `72.3`, as in the sample output.

Comment: @Cinnam just tested it and you're right, with an integer division the output would be `72.3` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = (int) (number1 + number2 + number3);
```

Take sum as double..No need to convert it into int.You will loose precision.

```
int product = (int) (number1 * number2 * number3);
```

Same thing applies here.

Rest looks fine.

Comment: that does not solve his problem. although this is correct.

Comment: Both the expression to calculate exp are same

Comment: @ThanigaiArasu correct. cause / binds stronger than +

Comment: @Thanigai..good catch.i thought it would make a difference.edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see only 1 problem:

```
double average = sum / 3;
```

is an integer division and will fail for some inputs(it will still work for your numbers) but it should be like this:

```
double average = sum / 3.0;
```

of you could change type of `sum` to `double`

Comment: the result is an integer... so no problem here. at least in this case

Comment: @haywire like i said, it will work for this numbers, but will eventually fail for other input

Comment: so, this is no answer to his problem at all. just a tip already mentioned in the comments

Comment: @haywire this is the only problem so this should fix his code, right? and it wasn't mentioned in comments.

Comment: actually it was first comment from Jordan.

Comment: @haywire "Well for one I don't see why you are declaring your numbers as doubles and then assigning them to an INT value. You are losing any decimal precision as it will only keep the INT." I can't see anything about integer division, you maybe?

Answer (score 0):

thx for everyone to help me .

i solve this

```
package home1;

public class Arithmetic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int number1 = 10;
        int number2 = 15;
        int number3 = 35;

        int sum =  (number1 + number2 + number3);
        double average = sum / 3.0;

        int product = (number1 * number2 * number3);
        double exp = (10.5 / number3) + (5 + number1 * number2) / (number3 - number1) * 12;

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The product is: " + product);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        System.out.println("The expression result is: " + exp);
    }
}
```